# What Is "Kaspersky Security Center Network Agent"?

Tags: antivirus

I see this in the program list on my office laptop. I believe it is the antivirus software installed by the official networking staff but I don't see where it is in my windows. I never see any updates or pop-ups.

Is it safe? I want to install another free antivirus like Avast but I don't think having two antivirus programs running concurrently is a good idea. Recently my iTunes account has been hacked so I am very concerned about this.

Answer (score 1):

We use Kaspersky in our network as well. Kaspersky Network Agent is the agent installed on client machines to report back to the security center (or the central point of command for your IT staff) The Agent itself is not responsible for the AV. Its simply the means to which the Endpoint manager(the AV on the system) can communicate with the Security Center server.

The agent also takes in the responsibility of installing applications remotely, managing endpoint encryption, and a few other Kaspersky features.

The reason you can't see the agent is because its a background service. Its just controlling and issuing the policies to the Endpoint Manager. Now if you can't see the endpoint manager it is possible for the IT staff to hide this with the "Self-defense" options. The IT staff where you work obviously does not want you tampering with the Endpoint manager and they would surely see the Audit arise in the Security Center if you did. For good reason though. Kaspersky will aide(not eliminate) in helping reduce your laptops attack surface and preventing possible compromise.

If you feel that only the agent is installed( and verified you don't see the signature "K" symbol in the task tray), it might be wise to call your IT department and ask if the system is being protected. Surely if they were using Kaspersky they could view the managed systems and see that your device is unprotected, if the agent is functioning and communicating properly.

Comment: I delete it and install a personal antivirus in my laptop. I never know if the IT department has actually installed a real antivirus client, update it, run scanning in my computer, so I better have one that I can control everything and regularly update and scan. Of course I can ask them but they are busy and I am busy so I do it my way.

Comment: Oh I work in IT, I know how busy we can appear for what seems like all the time :) That's good that you are being proactive for your own Computer protection! When you get the opportunity I would still ask them though. Having multiple AV software on one machine can cause system issues and instability. Best of luck to you Annie!

Comment: I uninstall the Kaspersky Network Agent

Comment: I don't see a "K" in my task tray. It looked like the "server team" had just installed a Kaspersky Network Agent in my "new laptop" and then they didn't do anything after that.

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky network agent is for administrative purposes via Kaspersky security center.

In this case antivirus and components installing via GPO by your tech. Stuff.

Check C:\Program files\Kaspersky lab for installed components and if so,ask your tech stuff to change policy and let you see tray image and alerts.

Comment: I don't see any Kaspersky  related programs running in task manager, is it normal? I only see the folder "NetworkAgent" in Kaspersky Lab Folder in Program Files (x86)

Comment: Check please Program files folder for x64 applications  and if no files here contact your tech team to install Kaspersky or remove network agent and install your own antivirus

Comment: There isn't Kaspersky lab folder or Kaspersky related folder in Program files folder for x64. So the networkAgent is actually doing nothing?

Comment: In short yes,it is not a protection ,it is management tool for other Kaspersky components. You are not secure,remove it and install any free antivirus

Comment: yeah I guess it is doing nothing if there is no other Kaspersky component....